# Netsuite Suitescript Reference Error selectmap is not defined

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have a user event script that is modifying a form upon load. I also have a client script(field change) that is attached to that form. Basically I have it to where when the user selects a vendor in the vendor field the script builds the sublist based on that criteria. Everything works, except I have a field called custpage_item_item that is a select field linked to the inventory item. I have done this many times but for some reason when I build the sublist I can't set the item in that field. It gives me "reference error selectmap is not defined".

```
var list = form.addSubList('custpage_sublist_items', 'inlineeditor', 'Demand 
Planner','custpage_item_tab');
list.addField('custpage_item_item', 'select', 'Item','item');
```

that is the field I am creating on the user event before load script.
In the client script I have a function that builds the sublist. I have 20 or so fields and all are working except the item field. If I change the field type to text it works. I have tested to make sure I am getting values. I am pulling the internal ID of the item (which I have done perfectly fine in other scripts).

```
nlapiSelectNewLineItem('custpage_sublist_items');
nlapiSetCurrentLineItemValue('custpage_sublist_items','custpage_item_item', 
itemId, false,true);
nlapiCommitLineItem('custpage_sublist_items');
```

I am at a loss as to the problem. The error does not make sense to me. The select field is defined. I can add items to the sublist manually just fine from the form

Answer (score 0):

Looks like selectmap is an undeclared variable or function.  Have you checked if there are any other client side scripts deployed on the record?  One of them might be executing when you are building the sublist.

Comment: So I created a custom record and used the custom form associated with it.I only have this client script attached to it.  But you might be onto something. When I created the record I set the option to store the form with the record, maybe that is causing the issue? I will disable that and try to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: I disabled the store form with record and that did not make a difference.